# Error when attempting Option(Option(Some)).flatten in Scala

Tags: scala

I am attempting to flatten an `Option(Option(Some))`, however when I attempt to compile the code I am receiving an error.

The code is as follows:

```
val foo = request.options.get(myKey).flatten
if(foo.get == bar) {...}
```

where `request.option.get(Key)` returns `Option[Any]`. In this case, the value associated with `myKey` is an `Option`, so `request.options.get(myKey)`
should return an `Option(Option(Some))`, which I have seen while debugging this code.

However, I receive the following errors:

```
Error: Cannot prove that Any <:< Option[B].

Error: not enough arguments for method flatten: (implicit ev: <: <[Any,Option[B]])Option[B]
Unspecified value parameter ev.
```

As far as I am aware, flatten should work in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because you see that `get(key)` returns a nested `Option` at *run time* doesn't change the fact that at *compile time* the signature of the method can only ensure that it returns `Option[Any]`. This is what the compiler is complaining about. It can prove that you have an `Option[Any]`, but it can't prove that you have an `Option[Option[_]]` at *compile time*.

The way `A <:< B` works is that it's just syntactic sugar for the type `<:<[A, B]`. This type represents evidence that the compiler knows `A <: B`. It's very existence is witness to that fact. If the compiler can't somehow prove that relationship, then there is no value for `A <:< B`. Therefore, `flatten` is an ordinary method with an implicit parameter of type `<:<[A,B]`. The compiler must resolve this parameter at compile time, or else the method call is invalid due to the lack of parameters. So at compile time, the compiler finds `A` to be `Any` (from `get(key)`), and `B` to be `Option[C]` (from `flatten`'s signature). Since it has no way to prove the relationship `Any <: Option[C]`, you get an error.

Imagine what would happen if this code *was* valid. Then, if anything ever happened to make your map return `Some(5)` instead of `Some(Some(blah))`, you'd still try to call `Some(5).flatten`, and then that will try to cast 5 to `Option`, and then... oops. Even if the logic of your program makes absolutely sure that your map gives you a nested `Option`, the compiler is obviously not magic and it can't be sure of that.

You can use partial functions or `match` to make this work, as the cases are then checked at run time and not compile time, and anything not matching the cases will throw a `MatchError` instead of being caught by the compiler.

**TL;DR** Generalized type constraints are resolved at compile time, which is not possible here since the return type is `Option[Any]`.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that `request.options.get(key)` return `Option[T]` doesn't mean that `request.options.get(Some(key))` returns `Option[Option[T]]`. I think what you want to do is getting the `key` out of the `Some` before passing it to `get`:

```
val theValueIWant = for {
  k <- myKey                   // get k out of the Some
  op <- request.options.get(k) // get the option (Some(value) or None)
  value <- op                  // get the value out of the option
} yield value
```

Comment: The issue was that the mapped value was an option. I see if I use match on the result I can get the behavior I need. For example:                       val bar = foo match {
          case None => //Key not present
          case Some(None) => //Key present in map but mapped to None
          case Some(value) => //Do something with the value from the map
        }

Comment: In order to understand what's happening, I need to know the type of `request.options` and `myKey`.